# Amazon S3 Policy: Manage folder level encryption

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-kms

I have a s3 bucket structure like..

```
device1/01
device2/01
device3/01
```

Each device has their own KMS key. I used boto3 to create structure and encryption.

```
s3_client.put_object(
    Body="Hello world",
    Bucket='MyBucket',
    Key="device1/01",
    ServerSideEncryption='aws:kms',
    SSEKMSKeyId='device1_kms_key_id'
)
```

Now if I keep using this `put_object()` with different KMS, will s3 policy get updated and have all KMS's access automatically?

Answer (score 0):

It's the Kms policy that needs to be updated so that you have access to the kms operations the you need for the specific keys.

Alternatively the iam policy could be updated to provide you access to the keys.

The s3 resource policy is unrelated.

None of this happen automatically.

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-bucket-access-default-encryption/